# How to remove columns that don't fit the parameters in R?

Tags: r, matrix

```
combo1 <- c(14,11)
combo2 <- c(3,10)
combo3 <- c(25,61)
combo4 <- c(12,13)
m <- matrix(c(combo1, combo2, combo3, combo4), ncol = 4)
```

I want to include columns that have both elements less than 16 and greater than 9.
So i want my matrix to only show (14,11) and (12,13)

Comment: oh sorry i accidentally wrote remove instead of include. ill edit it!

Answer (score 1):

We can use

```
m[,colSums(m < 16 & m > 9) == nrow(m)]
#       [,1] [,2]
#[1,]   14   12
#[2,]   11   13
```

If it is the other columns to keep

```
m[,colSums(m < 16 & m > 9) != nrow(m)]
#      [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    3   25
#[2,]   10   61
```